# Appium automation in Windows

Tags: appium, python-appium

So I've been trying to get my desired capabilities for a while and it's not working with the error of "failed to create session.

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a driver for `platformName` 'android'.

> Please check your desired capabilities", I've tried a few other settings but nothing is working help me

```
{
"platformName":"andriod",
"appium:platformVersion": "11.0",
"appium:deviceName":"Saint", "appium:automationName":"capability",
"appium:app": "path"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much help with what you have provided , but session is not getting created can have multiple scenarios.

1. Check your Appium server is running.
2. Define your driver correctly either appium/androiddriver/iOSdriver..
3. Your capabilities list are not full , so please try to paste full error since it will be helpful.

Just replace these capabilities from your code with these name/caps

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("udid", udid);
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "<Your App activity>");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("automationName","UiAutomator2");
```

}}